# .htaccess not running?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am new to linux administration and I am trying to restrict the outside world from accessing files in my /var/www folder.

I have done my research and found that .htaccess and .htpasswd was a good solution. So I found this online tutorial [here](http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection/) that told me to create the .htaccess file which looks like this

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

And then it had a password generate on the site so I put my password in and it told me to put this in my .htaccess file (the user is tom and I used X to hide my password)

```
tom:$XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/
```

I now put both files into my /var/www/ directory. However, when I try to access my files via a web browser Ex. XXX.XX.XXX/myfiles/test.... it still allows me access.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you restart your Apache?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes I did. Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Show the owner & permission of your `.htaccess` file.... Look into log files from Apache...

Comment: Have you checked your apache error log? Maybe it doesn't have access to the htacccess or password file. Also, in your virtual host spec, do you have the following: AllowOverride None? It needs to be set to AllowOverride All

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch -rw-r----

Comment: @Jodes Thanks for the reply! Do you mind explaning how to check the error log? Also I am not sure if I have that option set to "all". Can you tell me how to check that one as well? Thank you:)

Comment: I've posted an answer detailing how to find them. Hope it helps, add a comment to the answer if you still have problems. (And let me know what version of linux you're using)

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Check your apache error log. This could be:

- /var/log/apache2/error.log (Ubuntu)
- /var/log/httpd/error_log (RHEL / Red Hat / CentOS / Fedora)
- /var/log/httpd-error.log (FreeBSD)

For the AllowOverride setting, you will probably need to look in the following folder:

- /etc/apache2/sites-available/ (Ubuntu).

If you have the default setup, then you will want to look in the following file:

- /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

But if you have set up custom files for your domain, it might be in another file in that directory.

In the sites-available files, you might see something like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Change 'None' to 'All'.